# Show fetch results in render return() in React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fetch-api

My question is about how to show array results in render return().
I made a fetch to the API and now I get results that get stored in a array. I need to show this results but I tried with a for{} inside the return and it doesn't work, and I also tried with .map and the `map is undefined`.

```
fetch(url + '/couch-model/?limit=10&offset=0', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'JWT ' + (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token)
        }
    }).then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        } else {
            throw Error(res.statusText);
        }
    }).then(json => {
        this.setState({
             models: json.results
        }, () => {
            /*console.log('modelosJSON: ', json);*/
        });
    })

render() {
    const { isLoaded } = this.state;
    const modelsArray = this.state.models;

    console.log('modelos: ', modelsArray);

    if (!isLoaded) {
        return (
            <div>Loading...</div>
        )
    } else {

        return (
            <div>
                /*show results here*/
            </div>
        )
   }
}
```

The array is this: [image: modelsArray in console]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array of models is the `results` of the json returned from your `fetch`, so you can set that as `models` in your state instead, and set `isLoaded` to `true` so the loading indicator is hidden when the models are loaded.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { isLoaded: false, models: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url + "/couch-model/?limit=10&offset=0", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: "JWT " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")).token
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        } else {
          throw Error(res.statusText);
        }
      })
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          models: json.results,
          isLoaded: true
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoaded, models } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return <div>{models.map(model => <div key={model.id}>{model.code}</div>)}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked for code, but when I access the brand's **id** and **name**

                    `{models.map(model =>
                        <div key={model.brand.id}>{model.brand.name}</div>
                    )}`
returns the same position of the array. Repeats 10 times the same brand name

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro Hard to say without seeing your brand data. Don't use the brand id as `key`, because that might not be unique for every model. Use the model id instead, which will be unique. `key={model.id}`

Comment: See that image https://imgur.com/a/9CmvkmQ and thanks for the advice on the key @Tholle

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro `model.brand.name` looks correct if you want the brand name. It might be that some models are from the same brand. I don't know for sure.

Comment: I think I have to do another "for" to run the brand array

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro `brand` seems to be an object in the pictures you have shown, not an array.

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro Consider creating a new question if you can't find a satisfying solution after trying yourself.