# Count occurrences results from API JSON response in React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fetch

Based on this previous questions I made ([Show fetch results in render return() in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522379/show-fetch-results-in-render-return-in-react-js)), from which I received json results, I now need to count the number of sofas that each brand has. For example, Brand **X** has 2 occurences and Brand **Y** has 3043.
I get the brand from one sofa by calling `myUrlApi + /couch-model` on fetch and the json is something like what you can see in the picture below.
[image]

Has you can see each sofa has associated to itself a brand. What I want to count is how many sofa each brand has.

I'll put my current code here:

```
export class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token: {},
      isLoaded: false,
      models: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    /*code to generate token, not needed for the purpose of the question*/

    fetch(url + "/couch-model/?limit=9", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: "JWT " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")).token
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        } else {
          throw Error(res.statusText);
        }
      })
      .then(json => {
        this.setState(
          {
            models: json.results
          },
          () => {}
        );
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoaded, models } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          {models.map(model => (
            <a href="/sofa" key={model.id}>
              <div className="Parcelas">
                <img src={img_src} className="ParcImage" alt="sofa" />
                <h1>Sofá {model.name}</h1>
                <h2>
                  1,200<span>€</span>
                </h2>

                <p
                  className="Features"
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: model.description }}
                />

                <button className="Botao">
                  <p className="MostraDepois">Ver Detalhes</p>
                  <span>+</span>
                </button>
                <img
                  src="../../img/points.svg"
                  className="Decoration"
                  alt="points"
                />
              </div>
            </a>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Hope I was clear, ask if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Edit ojk8xwv22y]

if your results look like this as you said in your post :

```
{
  results: [
    {
      brand: { name: "Brand-A", image: "", etc: "..." },
      category: "A",
      code: "AAA",
      name: "SofaA",
      price: 1200
    },
    {
      brand: { name: "Brand-A", image: "", etc: "..."  },
      category: "A",
      code: "AAA",
      name: "SofaB",
      price: 1200
    },
    {
      brand: { name: "Brand-B", image: "", etc: "..."  },
      category: "A",
      code: "AAA",
      name: "SofaC",
      price: 1200
    }
  ]
}
```

You can add a state property like `sofasPerBrand` initialized to {}

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token: {},
      isLoaded: true,
      models: [],
      sofasPerBrand: {}
    };
  }
```

And add in the `setState` function in `componentDidMount` the RIYAJ KHAN reduce function like this :

```
this.setState(
      {
        models: json.results,
        sofasPerBrand: json.results.reduce((coundData, sofa, index) => {

          if (!!coundData[sofa.brand.name]) {
            coundData[sofa.brand.name] += 1;
          } else {
            coundData[sofa.brand.name] = 1;
          }
          return coundData;
        }, {})
      },
      () => { }
    );
```

then you can declare it in your render function :

```
const { isLoaded, models, sofasPerBrand } = this.state;
```

and use it like that any where :

```
<ul>
  {Object.keys(sofasPerBrand).map(brand=>(
      <li>{brand} : {sofasPerBrand[brand]}</li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Almost working and that's it! The setState can be outside the fetch, right? Because the results are being empty and saying `Line 88:  Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return`

Comment: When I gather sofasPerBrand with the previous fetch of brands, the brands stop showing

Comment: Different brands are getting the same numbers

Comment: can you share this on codesandbox or other tool like this ?

Comment: or even a sample of you results json

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/3xlwlw55yq
Now I think it counting different brands but putting them in the same, it makes 2 `span`, one with 9 and another with 11

Comment: if you put the `Object.keys(sofasPerBrand).map` thing inside the loop it will repeat the entire sofasPerBrand list over and over

Comment: Then how should I do it since I need the number to be next to the brand name as in the following image? https://imgur.com/a/qrGquEm <-- this image

Comment: hmm... maybe there is a conflict with brand declaration inside the loop : try to use this intead `{Object.keys(sofasPerBrand).map(b => (
                <span key={brand.id + "brand"}>{sofasPerBrand[b]}</span>
              ))}`

Comment: He counts 2 brands ut it displays in the same brand... @Jayffe

Comment: What is the 'b' for?? @Jayffe

Comment: I used 'b' instead of 'brand' because this code was already in a loop where 'brand' was declared to avoid name conflict

Comment: But can't I do both fetch in just onw loop?

Comment: I made a little codesandbox to explain the "b" thing if you want :) https://codesandbox.io/s/4q683kwrxx

Comment: Thank you!! I'm sorry for the bother all these days!

Answer (score 0):

One can use [`javascript#reducers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for it.

```
models.reduce((coundData,sofa,index)=>{

    if(!!coundData[sofa.brand.name]){
        coundData[sofa.brand.name] +=1; 
    }else{
        coundData[sofa.brand.name]=1;
    }

    return coundData;
}, {})
```

Comment: Its not redux,reducers is higher order function.

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm missunderstood, that's why I deleted the comment. I'll teste, thank you

Comment: Where should I put that @RIYAJ KHAN ?

Comment: `TypeError: models.reducer is not a function`

Comment: use .reduce instead of .reducer maybe `result.reduce((coundData,sofa,index)=>{`

Comment: I changed and doesn't give the error of before, but now does this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'BrandName' of undefined` @Jayffe